# Object not supported in this context while Creating the package in Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

Hi I am trying to execute below statements for creating a package , but i am getting an error saying

```
Error(3,1): PLS-00540: object not supported in this context.
```

When trying to change it to RECORD i am getting another error

```
Error(3,32): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "RECORD" when expecting one of the following:     
object opaque The symbol "object was inserted before "RECORD" to continue.
```

package Definition trying to execute

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE        "PKG_LOAN_LOGIC_SERVICE_V2" AS

TYPE LOAN_LOGIC_RESULT_TYPE AS OBJECT (
loanid NUMBER,
ret_value varchar2(500),
xPath varchar2(200)
);

TYPE LOAN_LOGIC_RESULTS_TABLE IS TABLE OF LOAN_LOGIC_RESULT_TYPE;

procedure PR_CORAL_LOAN_LOGIC( 
                      in_loan_id      IN   wcts.loans.loan_id%TYPE,
                      in_trans_id     IN   wcts.loans.loan_id%TYPE,
                      as_errm            out varchar2,
                      out_order_contents_tab out LOAN_LOGIC_RESULTS_TABLE
                      );
END PKG_LOAN_LOGIC_SERVICE_V2;
```

When i am trying to execute the user defined types in another standalone SQL Developer Window , its executing successfully .

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE LOAN_LOGIC_RESULT_TYPE AS OBJECT (
loanid NUMBER,
ret_value varchar2(500),
xPath varchar2(200)
);

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE LOAN_LOGIC_RESULTS_TABLE AS TABLE OF LOAN_LOGIC_RESULT_TYPE;
```

Why its not allowing me to run inside package ? or how i will create these types inside a package

Update:

```
create or replace procedure PR_CORAL_LOAN_LOGIC( 
                      in_loan_id      IN   wcts.loans.loan_id%TYPE,
                      in_trans_id     IN   wcts.loans.loan_id%TYPE,
                      as_errm            out varchar2,
                      out_order_contents_tab out LOAN_LOGIC_RESULTS_TABLE
                      )
is 
begin
for o in (SELECT    xpath_name    FROM  loan_logic  WHERE   attribute = 
 upper(TRIM('STATUS_0')))
  loop
  -- How i will get the user defined type here tp assign the values 
  --Assign the column values while iterating         
   END LOOP;
 end PR_CORAL_LOAN_LOGIC;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/adobj/declaring-initializing-objects-in-plsql.html#GUID-AA6DEB60-3D57-44CE-B0F6-D1AEC0B47AE0)

> You must define object types using the SQL statement CREATE TYPE

### EDIT

For example

```sql
create or replace procedure PR_CORAL_LOAN_LOGIC(out_order_contents_tab out LOAN_LOGIC_RESULTS_TABLE)
is
  obj LOAN_LOGIC_RESULT_TYPE;
begin
  obj := LOAN_LOGIC_RESULT_TYPE(2, 'return value', 'some/path');
  out_order_contents_tab := LOAN_LOGIC_RESULTS_TABLE();
  out_order_contents_tab.extend;
  out_order_contents_tab(1) := obj;
```

There are lots of examples available online, including [Working with Collections](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclemagazine/working-with-collections). Not to mention the [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#LNPLS005).

Comment: But it not allowing CREATE inside PACKAGE

Comment: @Vinoy exactly. Oracle **does not allow** to create a object type inside a package.

Comment: If so how I need to fix this

Comment: @Vinoy you already have fixed it. Use a separate CREATE TYPE statement.

Comment: I need this user defined types inside my procedure

Comment: @Vinoy you can use the database types inside your procedure. You don't have to define a type inside a package in order to use it in that package.

Comment: Just updated the Question , So inside the procedure how i can access that user defined type ?

Comment: For some reason the last statment is throwing error saying wrong type